# Classification problem and Associative rule mining

Tags: data-mining, large-data

Imagine, you are solving a multiclass classification problem with highly imbalanced class. The distribution of the classes is such that, you observed the majority class 99% of the times in the training data. Your model has 99% accuracy after taking the predictions on test data. Which of the following is true in such a case?
1) Accuracy is not a good metric for imbalanced class problems.
2) Accuracy is a good metric for imbalanced class problems.
3) Precision and Recall are good metrics for imbalanced class problems.
4) Precision and Recall are not good metrics for imbalanced class problems.

Which of the following statements are true, about frequent item-sets in the context of transactional databases
 1. Every maximal frequent itemset is a closed frequent itemset.
 2. Every closed frequent itemset is a maximal frequent itemset. 
 3. We can recover all frequent itemsets given all maximal frequent itemsets
 4. We can recover the frequencies of all frequent itemsets, given the frequencies of all maximal frequent itemsets.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, using accuracy alone as an evaluation metric for solving class-imbalance problems.

It is better to tune the cost function and the hyperparameters considering few metrics, including the overall accuracy, precision, recall, average precision, etc. Sometimes there exists a tradeoff between accuracy and average precision in class imbalance problems.

There is no "one right way," so you have to rely on heuristics to some extent.

For more information refer to these papers regarding class imbalance problems: [**Longadge et al 2013**](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1305/1305.1707.pdf), [**Guo et al 2008**](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/specific/congreso/guo_on_2008.pdf)

Comment: Are you talking about accuracy paradox?

Comment: @RimoSourav I do not know if it is called "the accuracy paradox", but you can't have your cake and eat it, too in most cases regarding data analysis.